# NSTask with bash script problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bash, shell, nstask

For example, i have this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $1;
```

And this cocoa wrapper for it:

```
NSTask *cd = [[NSTask alloc] init];

NSString *testFolder = [NSString stringWithString:@"/Users/test/Desktop/test 1"];

[cd setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];

[cd setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                              pathForResource:@"cd" ofType:@"sh"],testFolder, nil]];
[cd launch];
[cd release];
```

This is doesn't work correct. And the problem is space in folder name in testFolder. 
I'm trying to set `testFolder` like this:

`NSString *testFolder = [NSString stringWithString:@"/Users/test/Desktop/test\\ 1"]`

But this is also output same error:

`cd.sh: line 9: cd: /Users/test/Desktop/test: No such file or directory`

Paths without spaces (for example: `@"/Users/test/Desktop/test1"` ) works as well.

Comment: I've been searching for why I was getting "launch path not accessible" and your inclusion of your code made me realise I needed [cd setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];  It's not what your question was about, but it was still helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really a problem about `NSTask`. Open your terminal (and run `bash` if you use `tcsh`), and do

```
$ mkdir foo\ bar
$ FUBAR=foo\ bar
$ cd $FUBAR
```

This doesn't work. You need to do

```
$ cd "$FUBAR"
```

instead. This is because of the expansion rule of the `sh`. Read the manual of bash e.g. [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html), the section called **EXPANSION**. [This section](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/shell_scripts/shell_scripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004268-CH237-SW4) from the shell scripting primer might help, too.